# Android LibGdx - Thread are hanging most of the time

Tags: java, android, libgdx, java-threads

I am developing a news screen in android device using LigGdx framework. The news Api gives me the link of the PNG type image. In LibGdx, I am creating a new threads to download the image and coverting it into sprite. While doing so the app is getting struck after some calls. This happens 50 % of the time. Could you please let me know how to avoid such type of hanging ?

```
private void doIcoItemSetup(){
    setIcoItemImage(i);
    }
}

private void setIcoItemImage(final int i) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        /** Downloads the content of the specified url to the array. The array has to be big enough. */
        private int download (byte[] out, String url) {

            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(false);
                conn.setUseCaches(true);
                conn.connect();
                in = conn.getInputStream();
                int readBytes = 0;
                while (true) {
                    int length = in.read(out, readBytes, out.length - readBytes);
                    if (length == -1) break;
                    readBytes += length;
                }
                return readBytes;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return 0;
            } finally {
                StreamUtils.closeQuietly(in);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run () {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[200 * 1024]; // assuming the content is not bigger than 200kb.
            System.out.println("Testing 1111 " + game.icoItemList.get(i).getImageURL());
            int numBytes = download(bytes, game.icoItemList.get(i).getImageURL());
            if (numBytes != 0) {
                // load the pixmap, make it a power of two if necessary (not needed for GL ES 2.0!)
                Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(bytes, 0, numBytes);
                final int originalWidth = pixmap.getWidth();
                final int originalHeight = pixmap.getHeight();
                int width = MathUtils.nextPowerOfTwo(pixmap.getWidth());
                int height = MathUtils.nextPowerOfTwo(pixmap.getHeight());
                final Pixmap potPixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, pixmap.getFormat());
                potPixmap.drawPixmap(pixmap, 0, 0, 0, 0, pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight());
                pixmap.dispose();
                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        System.out.println("Testing 1111 -------------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Testing 1111  originalWidth,originalHeight : " + originalWidth + "," + originalHeight );
                        game.icoItemList.get(i).setIcoItemSprite(new Sprite(new TextureRegion(new Texture(potPixmap), 0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight)));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: i am getting Buffer not allocated issue ? how to resolve it ..as i am new libgdx development

Comment: @KoVartthan I am not getting any error of that kind.